# How can I evaluate if an alert exists in casperjs?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

```js
casper.waitForAlert(function(response) {
    this.echo("Alert received: " + response.data);
});
```

Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting. // I want the code to continue and store in a variable whether or not an alert exists

For example... if (exists.alert)..{}   :-(

Comment: Maybe try to refine your question. I do not understand it.

Comment: Seconding the previous commenter, as it is currently, it's unclear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I'm browsing a web page, there are times when clicking on a button, it shows an alert (not popup), what I really want is to know if I showed the alert or not showing it by storing it in a variable and that the script To continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you should use the onTimeout option for the waitForAlert function.
If we define the myAlert variable outside (globally) then you can use it from anywhere. Also by using an object we have an advantage that we can save for example the alert value with ease

```
var myAlert;

casper.waitForAlert(
    function(response) {
        myAlert = { exists:true, value:response.data }; 
    },
    function() {
        myAlert = { exists:false }; 
    });

casper.then(function() {        
    if ( myAlert.exists ) {
        this.echo( "Alert exists and value is: " + myAlert.value );
    } else {
        this.echo( "Alert doesn't exists" );
    }
});
```